# How to delete rows from join-table (ManyToMany) in Doctrine?

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a join-table which is created by using `@ORM\ManyToMany` annotation in Symfony2/Doctrine.
It joins `Category` and `Parameter` table.

Now I want to delete all parameters from the Parameter table. Because there are foreign key constraints defined on join-table I can't just delete rows from Parameter table. First I have to delete child rows from join-table. But Dotrine's DQL syntax require to give a name of the entity, like:

```
DELETE Project\Entity\EntityName
```

But what is the name of the join-table entity generated by using ManyToMany association? How to deal with it?

Alternately, how can I set ON UPDATE CASCADE and ON DELETE CASCADE on foreign key constraints in join-table defined by `@ORM\ManyToMany` annotation.

**EDIT:**

join-table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories_params` (
    `category_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `param_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`category_id`, `param_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_87A730CB12469DE2` (`category_id`),
    INDEX `IDX_87A730CB5647C863` (`param_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `categories_params_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `allegro_category` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `categories_params_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`param_id`) REFERENCES `category_param` (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

`on UPDATE` and `on DELETE` by default are set to `RESTRICT`

**THE FINAL SOLUTION WOULD BE:**

```
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CategoryParam", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="categories_params",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="param_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")})
```

Comment: Can you post the table schema? I suspect you have a FK constraint on the join table to remove rows if any row is removed from Category or Parameter table. If this is the case, all you have to do is delete from Parameter table, and MySQL will take care of the rest for you.

Comment: Actually the FK constraint in my join-table prevent deleting rows from parent table (Parameter) if they are referenced by join-table. I can change this constraint in db schema, but I wanted to do that using Doctrine's annotation (to be able to generate complete schema from code without manually tweaking the database).

Comment: Would you mind posting the schema? I'm interested to see if the FK handling is done at the app layer via Doctrine, or if Doctrine is just abstracting what MySQL does already.

Comment: Thanks for posting the schema. I'm curious though, why wouldn't you put the DELETE CASCADE with the FK? By doing this you can manually delete a row from Parameter table via the MySQL command line, and any matching rows in the join table will also be removed.

Comment: I would like to apply DELETE CASCADE on FK, but I don't want to do it myself in database. I would like to use some kind of metadata for Doctrine that would do it automatically while generating schema from model.

Comment: For now I will modify database by hand than.

Comment: Understood, it's all about preference. Just wanted to make aware of another solution to the same problem.

Comment: It seems that setting onDelete="CASCADE" directly in database is not a good option. Everytime I run "php app/console doctrine:schema:update" it overwrites FK settings to its defaults (onDelete="RESTRICT").

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To set cascade on doctrine level:

```
@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Target", inversedBy="inverse", cascade={"remove", "persist"})
```

More info: [Doctrine2 Annotation Reference](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html).

To set cascade on mysql level:

```
@ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", onUpdate="CASCADE")
```

Comment: Just curious, but couldn't he just delete the rows from the Parameter table, and with the FK to the join table, the join rows will also be deleted? I haven't delved into D2 yet, but it seems un-necessary for the ORM to do what the database does natively.

Comment: @Inori cascade={"remove", "persist"} doesn't affect database schema, it comes into play when you remove entities using EntityManager.

Comment: @Digital Precision by default FK constraint doesn't allow deleting rows from parent table (Parameter) if they are referenced by join-table. That why I asked how can I change this constraint to cascade delete.

Comment: @JohnM2: Your OP stated "Now I want to delete all parameters from the Parameter table." but you were running into FK issues. If you delete from the Parameter side, you should be fine, because the FK would be on the join table, not the parameter table. So when you delete a row from the parameter table, it would cascade to the join table.

Comment: @Digital Precision FK constraints on join-table are applied when something happens to rows in table which is referenced by a constraint (join-table). So constraint is set on join-table but it concerns Parameter table.

Comment: @Inori http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-objects.html#removing-entities "Using foreign key semantics onDelete="CASCADE" can force the database to remove all associated objects internally. This strategy is a bit tricky to get right but can be very powerful and fast. You should be aware however that using strategy 1 (CASCADE=REMOVE) completely by-passes any foreign key onDelete=CASCADE option, because Doctrine will fetch and remove all associated entities explicitly nevertheless."

Comment: With cascade="remove" you won't have to deal with the fact that you might have entities that have no representation in database anymore (i.e. if you have onDelete=cascade, you delete an entity and it runs mysql cascades, but object instances are still present until next request), so I'd still recommend what I wrote in my answer. In case you still want mysql one, then adding 'onDelete="CASCADE"' as a m2m option will most likely work.